# Looking for an old post I’ve seen before

Tags: discussion, support

I remember seeing a post before that concerned how to bring a claim in England against an anonymous “placeholder” defendant whose address for service (or other details like complete name) one doesn’t know, and then once the claim is opened apply to the court for it to compel certain third parties to divulge information that they may hold which would aid in filling in the missing gaps to identify the defendant. Does anyone else have any tips for finding this old post, or are you able to find it?

Note: I recall this post containing an answer that suggested a specific provision with charter and verse section numbers etc for how to submit the application to the court to ask it to compel an organisation to divulge the instruction so as to unmask the defendant.

Comment: I wanted to correct your spelling from charter to chapter. But I dont have enough rep and got a pop-up saying 'Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites.'

Answer (score 1):

Do you happen to look for a John Doe vs. Richard Roe case? Those were stand-in names for land-right cases in medieval England. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe#History

Answer (score 1):

Is this it. I searched for placeholder and got this answer ( I think it was @Ricks)

https://law.stackexchange.com/a/90183/39555